# Question about complexity of algorithms

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I came across this symbol $2^{\mathcal{O} (n)}$ and I can't figure out what is means. What complexity class is this?

Comment: (@lox: erm - no. *exponent growing linear in $n$, at most*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can understand it as set $\{2^{f(n)}: f \in O(n)\}$.

For example any $n^k,k>0$, will be in $2^{O(n)}$: $n^k=2^{k\log_2 n}$ and  we have $\log_2 n \in O(n)$.

**Note**: I especially not write $k \cdot \log_2 n \in O(n)$, because multiplication on positive constant has no influence.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really helpful.